SEDE SQL Query suggestion for user votes cast this month/week?
In SEDE is there a table I can query or a SQL command that I can find the user votes cast this month/week? As Listed in the user's "Activity" page?
Such as this:


You can get votes, but they're only associate to posts and not to the users who cast them. The Votes table's UpMod and DownMod vote types are for upvotes and downvotes of logged-in users, and PostFeedback has similar votes, but anonymous votes (anonymous or unregistered users).
The Users table has all-time upvotes cast and all-time downvotes cast, so if you query every week and store the values locally, you can just diff the stuff to get the change in each SEDE refresh period.
